# How to move chunks of a numpy array without loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an numpy array organized like this, where 2 rows constitute a chunk, so there are 4 chunks total:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0.],
[1., 1., 1., 1.],
[1., 1., 1., 1.],
[2., 2., 2., 2.],
[2., 2., 2., 2.],
[3., 3., 3., 3.],
[3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

And I want to transform the array such that every other chunk is appended to the first chunk's columns:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
[2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
[2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Tried the brute-force approach with for loop over the chunks. This works but looking for a faster approach. Any insights appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should always tag your questions with `python` as well as `numpy`, that will ensure they get seen by the largest audience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about some reshaping and transposing magic?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [2., 2., 2., 2.],
    [2., 2., 2., 2.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.],
    [3., 3., 3., 3.]
])

X, Y, H, W = 2, 2, 2, 4

out = arr.reshape(X, Y, H, W).swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(X * H, Y * W)
```

out:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

---

Explanation:

There are logically 4 dimensions at play:

- Each chunk is `W` wide. In this case `W = 4`;
- Each chunk is `H` high. In this case `H = 2`;
- You want to put these chunks in a grid. The width of this grid is `Y`. In this case `Y = 2`;
- The height of this grid is unspecified, but is unambiguously determined by the chosen `Y`. In this case, with `N = 4` total chunks, we could say the height of the grid `X = N / Y = 2`.

Currently, the memory order is `(X Y H) W`. This means that the envisioned "axes" `X, Y, H` are grouped together on axis 0 in the original array, thus of length `X * Y * H = 8`.

Your desired output array has ordering `(X H) (Y W)`. Thus:

```
out = (
    arr                     # (X Y H) W
    .reshape(X, Y, H, W)    #  X Y H W
    .swapaxes(1, 2)         #  X H Y W     
    .reshape(X * H, Y * W)  # (X H) (Y W)
)

# Note that reshaping can only ever "regroup" axes,
# and that transposing can only ever reorder "groups" of axes.
```

Comment: Awesome! How can this scale as the array dimensions and chunk sizes grow?

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```
chunks = arr.reshape(4, 2, 4)
np.hstack([np.vstack(chunks[::2, :, :]), np.vstack(chunks[1::2, :, :])])
```

Output:

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with slicing:

```
x = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 0.],
[1., 1., 1., 1.],
[1., 1., 1., 1.],
[2., 2., 2., 2.],
[2., 2., 2., 2.],
[3., 3., 3., 3.],
[3., 3., 3., 3.]])

np.concatenate((x[::2], x[1::2]), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good night @dmn, I got your code and put it to run on the machine. If a question without loop handling, per your example, if by appending the first column, the fastest method would be [concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

cell:

```py
import numpy as np
group = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 1., 1.],
                  [1., 1., 1., 1.],
                  [2., 2., 2., 2.],
                  [2., 2., 2., 2.],
                  [3., 3., 3., 3.],
                  [3., 3., 3., 3.]])

group
```

output:

```py
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

cell:

```py
len(group)
```

output:

```py
8
```

cell:

```py
np.concatenate((group))
```

output:

```py
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2.,
       2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.])
```

cell:

```py
len(np.concatenate((group)))
```

output:

```py
32
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this "in-place" by swapping the second and third rows of each group of four rows before giving the array its final shape:

```
import numpy as np
group = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                  [1., 1., 1., 1.],
                  [1., 1., 1., 1.],
                  [2., 2., 2., 2.],
                  [2., 2., 2., 2.],
                  [3., 3., 3., 3.],
                  [3., 3., 3., 3.]])


group[1::4],group[2::4] = group[2::4],group[1::4].copy()
group.shape = (group.shape[0]//2,-1)

print(group)    
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
 [2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

To demonstrate that this combines the appropriate lines, if you start out with:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
 [11. 12. 13. 14.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.]
 [15. 16. 17. 18.]
 [21. 22. 23. 24.]
 [31. 32. 33. 34.]
 [25. 26. 27. 28.]
 [35. 36. 37. 38.]]
```

You will get :

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.]
 [11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18.]
 [21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28.]
 [31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38.]]
```